# How do I disable alt-codes in dwm?

Tags: x-dwm

I'm running ubuntu with dwm just for learning, but I cannot use any commands which use the meta/alt key because any further keys with alt are interpreted as an alt-code and prints out accented characters. This makes emacs meta keys and other terminal commands impossible.

I have noticed that the virtual terminals do not have this issue.

Are there any way to disable alt-codes without remapping the alt-key?

Answer (score 0):

Accent characters should only be printed when you use right alt. You should be able to use alt keybindings with left alt if you map MODKEY to different key. For example #define MODKEY Mod4Mask.